# I am having issues with session in PHP - Verions PHP5.3 -> PHP5.2

Tags: php, session

I have a code using Sessions in PHP. In localhost they are in version 5.3 working fine.

Today I need to migrate this code to a server with PHP 5.2 but in the firsts tests I found a big issue in the sessions.

Is there any change in the session´s function?

I only use basic ones:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["$foo"] = $bar;
unset($_SESSION["foo"]);
```

Thanks,

---

**EDIT**

Guys, I will describe my problem.

This part of the code:

```
$_SESSION['session'] = $session; 
$_SESSION['valorTotalS'] = $valorTotalS;
$_SESSION['frete'] = $frete;
$_SESSION["cliente"] = $cliente_id;

$carrinho = new carrinho($bd);
$car = $carrinho->geraId();

$carrinho->getCarrinhoSession($session);
$carrinho_id = $carrinho->getId();

$carrinho->setCliente_id($cliente_id);
$carrinho->setCodigo($car);

$frete = tiraVirgula($frete);

$carrinho->setValor($valorTotalS);
$carrinho->setFrete($frete);
$carrinho->setStatus("Aguardando Contato");
$carrinho->setPeso($peso);

$carrinho->closeCarrinho();
$carrinho->saveCarrinho();
```

---

In localhost5.3 server, $carrinho is updated.

In PHP 5.2 server the $carrinho is not updated.

Comment: You should describe the issue you are having

Comment: Which big issue might that be?

Comment: It is most likely a php.ini setup issue. Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Note that `"$foo"` will be evaluated to the value of `$foo`.

Comment: *(changelog)* http://www.php.net/ChangeLog-5.php

Comment: `Fixed handling of session variable serialization on certain prefix characters. Reported by Stefan Esser. (Ilia)` ... make sense ?

Comment: What do you mean by "$carrinho is updated" - updated when? $carrinho is not even mentioned with session, how it's related to sessions?

Answer (score 0):

At a glance, `$_SESSION["$foo"]` is not the same as `$_SESSION["foo"]`.  `$foo` is a variable.  If it happened to contain the text "blah", the statement would evaluate to `$_SESSION["blah"]` which is totally different from `$_SESSION["foo"]`.

Comment: Oh First of all, in the code $_SESSION["$foo"] it was a miss speling.

Comment: @Felipe : you can always update your question!!! please do that so that its easier to understand what exactly you are looking for!